# simplex of rational distances

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

I want to know if this result is true: let $a_1,...,a_{n+1}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\epsilon>0$, then $\exists a_{n+1}'\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that for $i=1,...,n$, $\parallel a_i-a_{n+1}'\parallel\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\parallel a_{n+1}-a_{n+1}'\parallel<\epsilon$. If it is how i can prove it ? I'm trying to prove it by induction, for $n=1$ case it seems to be trivial since: take $a_1,a_2\in \mathbb{R}$, if $|a_1-a_2|\in \mathbb{Q}$ we are done, if not, without loss of generality take $a_1=0$ so $|a_2|\in \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$. Let $V=B_\epsilon(a_2)$ because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ take $a_2'\in\mathbb{Q}\cap V$ and then $|a_1-a_2'|=|a_2'|\in\mathbb{Q}$. But when I'm trying to apply the induction hypothesis I don't know how to advance. Someone have any idea ?

Thanks for  your time.

Comment: The base case is trivial since: take $a_1,a_2\in \mathbb{R}$, if $|a_1-a_2|\in \mathbb{Q}$ we won, if not, without loss of generality suppose that  $a_1=0$ then $|a_2|\in \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$. Let $V=B_\epsilon(a_2)$ because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense $\mathbb{R}$ take $a_2'\in\mathbb{Q}\cap V$ and then $|a_1-a_2'|=|a_2'|\in\mathbb{Q}$. But when im trying to use the induction hypothesis I dont know how to advance. @quasi

Comment: For the "if not" case, you assumed $a_1 = 0$ and $a_2 \notin \mathbb{Q}$; no problem there. But then you can't have both $a_2'\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $a_2-a_2' \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Ok, my mistake -- you don't need $a_2 - a_2' \in Q$; it wasn't specified that $|a_{n+1} -a'_{n+1}|$ had to be rational.

Comment: I don´t understand your point, I´m saying that there is a rational number $a_2'$ such that $|a_2-a_2'|<\epsilon$, I think it is true, not ? @quasi

Comment: So, back to the drawing board! Now it seems like it's true. So next up, the case $n=2$. Induction probably won't need the $n=2$ case, but that case will probably show how to make the induction work.

Comment: Yes, your proof for the case $n=1$ is fine -- I misread the statement of the problem.

Comment: Also, if in your post, you had shown your work for the case $n=1$, and perhaps an attempt at the case $n=2$, (as well as mentioning that you can't see how to proceed by induction),  I think that would have avoided getting all the negative votes.

Comment: Ok, i will edit the post, and let me show you mi idea for the $n=2$ case.

Comment: Still, as you work on the case $n=2$, stay objective. If you can't prove it, perhaps try for a counterexample.

Comment: Ok, I see how it works for $n=2$ (and the general case should be analogous). Suppose $a_1,a_2,a_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2$. If $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are collinear, it reduces to the $n=1$ case. So assume they're not collinear. Let $V=B_\epsilon(a_3)$. Consider the map $V \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $p \to (d(a_1,p),d(a_2,p))$. The map is clearly continuous. Argue that for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, the map injective, hence the image has nonempty interior, so must contain a rational point.

Comment: So, the induction is only needed for the scenario where the $(n+1)$ points are not affinely independent. If they're affinely independent, the proof can proceed without induction using a strategy analogous to the one used for the $n=2$ non-collinear case.

Comment: Sorry, I don´t understand you how the map is define, what does it mean pto? And the map goes from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}^2? @quasi

Comment: The variable $p$ is an arbitrary point of $V$.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll write it as an answer, so it can be edited.

Comment: Ok I aprreciate it a lot, thanks for your ideas, they help me a lot ! @quasi

Comment: Update: I edited my posted proof, removing all traces of induction. Perhaps induction can be made to work, but not in the way I had previously suggested. To see why, just consider the collinear case for $n=2$. The line through $a_1,a_2,a_3$ need not have any rational points, so the reduction to the $n=1$ case doesn't work. But the invariance of domain argument works even if the points $a_1,...,a_{n+1}$ are affinely dependent, just so long as $a_1,...,a_{n+1}$ are distinct. Thus, my revised proof is non-inductive and works for the general $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial result . . .

Suppose $a_1,...,a_{n+1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are such that $a_1,...,a_n$ are affinely independent.

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Next, choose a point $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
\begin{align*}
&{\small{\bullet}}\;\;b\,\text{ is affinely independent of }\,a_1,...,a_{n}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\\[6pt]
&{\small{\bullet}}\;\;d(a_{n+1},b) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}\\[6pt]
\end{align*}

Let ${\displaystyle{
V=B\left(b,{\small{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}}\right)
}}$ be the open ball of radius ${\small{\displaystyle{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}}}$, centered at $b$.

Consider the map $f : V \to \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $f(p) = (d(a_1,p),...,d(a_n,p))$.

The map $f$ is clearly continuous.

If we assume $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small, then since the $n+1$ points $a_1,...,a_n,b$ are affinely independent, it follows that $f$ is injective,

Update: I'm sure the above claim is valid, but it needs support. As of now, it's a gap in the proof. But assuming the above claim is proved, then by

$\qquad$https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

the image of $f$ has nonempty interior, so must contain a rational point (i.e., an element of $\mathbb{Q}^n)$.

Let $a_{n+1}' \in V$ be such that $f(a_{n+1}') \in \mathbb{Q}^n$.

Then $d(a_k,a_{n+1}')$ is rational for $k = 1,...,n$.

Also, $d(a_{n+1},a_{n+1}') \le d(a_{n+1},b)+ d(b,a_{n+1}') <  
{\small{
\displaystyle{
\frac{\epsilon}{2}
}}}
+
{\small{
\displaystyle{
\frac{\epsilon}{2}
}}}
= 
\epsilon
$.

So all the required conditions for $a_{n+1}'$ are satisfied.

Thus, assuming the gap I noted is filled, the main claim is verified for the case where $a_1,...,a_n$ are affinely independent.

I'm fairly sure the main claim is still true without the assumption that $a_1,...,a_n$ are affinely independent. The idea is that, since $b$ is affinely independent of $a_1,...,a_n$, the image of the map $f$ has nonempty interior, even if $f$ is not injective.

Thus, more work is needed. Help would be welcome.